# ilovepdf rest api with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, pdf

I want to integrate ilovepdf rest api to my wordpress website , to provide pdf online services, I tried to manage it to work but there's one problem which is ( double link request ) when the user should download the modified pdf files , this problem appears and the file never be downloaded.

```
<?php
// include the autoloader
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
// if manual installation has been used, comment the line that requires the autoload and uncomment this line:
// require_once('../init.php');

use Ilovepdf\CompressTask;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    // Check if the file was uploaded without errors
    if (isset($_FILES["pdf_file"]) && $_FILES["pdf_file"]["error"] === 0) {
        // Get the temporary file name and original name of the uploaded file
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["pdf_file"]["tmp_name"];
        $originalFileName = $_FILES["pdf_file"]["name"];
        
        // Move the uploaded file to a desired location (optional, you can keep it in the same location)
        $destination = __DIR__ . '/' . $originalFileName;
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempFileName, $destination)) {
            // You can get your key pair from https://developer.ilovepdf.com/user/projects
            $myTask = new CompressTask('project_public_96a844e87ddc4b836c702c8e7f19a675_5IpO0d4ae81b82fe0dc72c4d6e3ede1ea3b4e', 'secret_key_eea03bd3fc3bb56f72f388a013311b8c_edACC02605b61b1f4ce1868bb0f2e3e73641b');

            // Add the file from user input to the task
            $file = $myTask->addFile($destination, $originalFileName);

            // Process the files
            
            $myTask->execute();

            $myTask->outputFileName = $originalFileName;
            
            // Download the compressed file to the user's browser
            $myTask->toBrowser();
            
            // Delete the uploaded file after download
            unlink($destination);
            // Note: In a production application, you may want to handle error cases, file size limits, and other validations.
        } else {
            echo "Error moving the uploaded file.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error uploading the file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you write error message? as well?

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze the code doesnt throw any error , the doublicate link request errors shows in my inter download manager when trying to download the modified file .

Comment: What is "inter download manager"? Are you talking about an external download manager outside of the browser?

Comment: @CBroe yes , the broweser does not download at all, i tested in pc and mobile , nothing is being downloaded , but i refered to ( internet download manager ) program because no errors shows in the code .

Comment: Still not clear what "dublicate link request error" means, is that supposed to be the error message quoted _verbatim_? What do you see happening in the network panel of your browser dev tools? What response does the initial request get? And is there more than one request to this endpoint happening?